# XPATH clarification

Tags: browser-automation, xpath

[image]

Refer: Picture of elements of HTML screenshot
I am trying to get XPATH

1. > //*[@id="pg:pbEdit:conlist"] or //select[@id="pg:pbEdit:conlist"]

- Works but I want to be precise not multiple selections So

2. I tried

> //select[@id='pg:pbEdit:conlist' and @value='NEW_CONTACT']

- This does not work (Please help me understand why as I see "value" is attribute.

3. I tried this xpath

> `//select[@id='pg:pbEdit:conlist' and contains(text(),'James Baugh')]`

Please can you advise me on what's going wrong.

Comment: `//select` whatever condition you are using in `[]` always selects `select` element. If you need to query its children you need to add something like `//select[YOUR_CONDITION]/option[YOUR_CONDITION]`

Comment: Thank you @alexeyR. Much Appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could get this working, I understand Option is the tag always thought part of Selet tag ..

> `//select[@id='pg:pbEdit:conlist']/option[contains(text(),'James')]`
> However still keen to know why this should not work `
> //select[@id='pg:pbEdit:conlist' and @value='NEW_CONTACT']

`

Comment: Thank you @PDHide. Thank you for your time, really appreciate

Answer (score 1):

```
//select[@id='pg:pbEdit:conlist' and @value='NEW_CONTACT']
```

Refers to same element , that is the select tag

It will look for select tag with id pg:pbEdit:conlist and value NEW_CONTACT

But there is no tag like that , in your Dom select tag element has only ID

You should use:

```
   //select[@id='pg:pbEdit:conlist']/option[@value='NEW_CONTACT']
```

`

This ensures that the locator looks for select tag with the specified ID and then the child of that select tag that contains option has the tag name , and New contact as the value

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, as I was about to ask another question, Please may I know how to mark this question as answered. Thank you both

Comment: Refer this - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Comment: Protocoder, I hope the links JAINAM provided will help you. If you still need assistance please reply to this comment. Thank you!

Comment: Sorry could not login here, Yes I now I know how to mark as solved. Cheers